# Custom Shelve Implementation in Python

Tags: python, shelve

I am very new to Python.A have a requirement to use a custom Shelve implementation where it can be backed by MySQL in stead of FileSystem. The requirement looks a bit odd as you may think if I need a DB store why not to use some driver adhering to Py DB api. The real problem goes like this.
There is already a shelve implementation in a open sourced project which uses the FileSystem to persist the data. Now suppose I need to provide a way where it can use either FileBased or MySQL based store and without changing the already made calls and the calls which may be added in future, I need to find a way out where the dict in Shelve can be backed by MySQL.

Will there be a way out?
Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: How are we supposed to know if it's possible to do this without changing your implementation if we don't see your implementation. The only thing I can say is check out the pickle module.

Comment: The python docs has a link to the latest shelve module python source code: http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/shelve.py?view=markup Maybe it can help?

Comment: Thnx much to both of you. I could achieve it by implementing the interfaces exposed by shelve where I am using the the MySQL queries to get/set the data directly. I know this approach could be problematic where there is much interaction with the DB. But in my case both READ/WRITE OP are minimal hence it suits what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably far too late to help you, but I just discovered [Shove](https://bitbucket.org/lcrees/shove/overview).

> Common object storage frontend that supports dictionary-style access, object serialization and compression, and multiple storage and caching backends.